# JavaFX StackPane snapshot doesn't display background layer

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application, snapshot

I have two charts overlaying in a StackPane (one bar graph and one line graph that contains 3 series).

The line graph is on top of the bar one and is displayed correctly in the app. However, when I try to take a snapshot, the bar graph doesn't show up.

I tried taking a snapshot of the node as well as the whole scene but it still doesn't show up. I guess it has to do with the fact that it's a background node, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it show.

```
 WritableImage snapshot = stackPane.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(),null);

 ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot,null),"png",new File("chart.png"));
```

I'm editing in order to add the rest of the code:

The Controller:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML StackPane stackPane;


    public void onBtnClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Graphs graphs = new Graphs();
                    StackPane secondaryStackpane = graphs.call();

                    stackPane.getChildren().addAll(secondaryStackpane.getChildren());

                    WritableImage snapshot = stackPane.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(),null);
                    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot,null),"png",new File("chart.png"));


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The Graphs class:

```
public class Graphs extends Task {

    StackPane stackPane;
    NumberAxis yAxis;
    NumberAxis yAxisRight;
    CategoryAxis xAxis;
    NumberAxis yAxisRightBlank;

    public Graphs() {

        stackPane = new StackPane();

        xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"));

        yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 70, 10);
        yAxisRight = new NumberAxis(0, 14, 1);
        yAxisRightBlank = new NumberAxis(0, 15, 1);
        yAxisRightBlank.setSide(Side.RIGHT);

        xAxis.setLabel("Month");
        yAxis.setLabel("Level");
        yAxisRight.setLabel("Level (u)");


    }


    void createGraph() {


        BarChart<String, Number> barChart = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        barChart.setLegendVisible(false);
        barChart.setAnimated(false);
        barChart.getXAxis().setVisible(true);

        barChart.getData().addAll(getAverageLoadPerFTE());


        LineChart<String, Number> lineChartEffective = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxisRight);
        lineChartEffective.setLegendVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.setAnimated(false);
        lineChartEffective.setCreateSymbols(true);
        lineChartEffective.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.getXAxis().setVisible(true);
        lineChartEffective.getYAxis().setVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.getYAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.getYAxis().setOpacity(0);

        lineChartEffective.getData().addAll(getEffectiveCustomerSupport());

        barChart.setAnimated(false);
        barChart.applyCss();
        barChart.layout();

        lineChartEffective.setAnimated(false);
        lineChartEffective.applyCss();
        lineChartEffective.layout();


        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(barChart, lineChartEffective);
    }

    public StackPane call() {

        createGraph();

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateProgress(100, 100);
                System.out.println("from call " + progressProperty());
            }
        });

        return this.stackPane;
    }

    private XYChart.Series<String,Number> getEffectiveCustomerSupport() {
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Jan", 2.9 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Feb", 2.7 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Mar", 3.3 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Apr", 3.4 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("May", 3.3 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Jun", 3.2 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Jul", 3.3 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Aug", 4 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Sep", 3.8 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Oct", 4.1 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Nov", 0 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Dec", 0 ));


        series.setName("Effective customer support");

        return series;
    }

    private XYChart.Series<String,Number> getAverageLoadPerFTE() {
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Jan", 58 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Feb", 54 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Mar", 47 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Apr", 34 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("May", 33 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Jun", 32 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Jul", 30 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Aug", 36 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Sep", 29 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Oct", 33 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Nov", 0 ));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Dec", 0 ));



        series.setName("Average load per FTE");

        return series;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to [turn off animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596688/javafx-i-want-to-save-chart-image-completely).

Comment: I set the animation as false immediately after creating the charts, I don’t think this is it... :/

Comment: Then provide a [mcve] if you want to get help.

Comment: I edited my question, not sure if it gets reposted after the edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Stacking charts in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395469/javafx-stackpane-snapshot-doesnt-display-background-layer/59430841#59430841)

Answer (score 0):

This question is essentially a duplicate of:

- [Stacking charts in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788117/stacking-charts-in-javafx)

But I'll provide an answer which is based on the code in your question so you can understand a bit better about how the answer is applied in your particular situation.

Basically, the main issue is that you aren't setting the background color of the graphs to a transparent color, so when one chart is painted over the other, the chart behind is not visible.  This had nothing to do with the snapshot routine, the charts wouldn't have displayed as you wish if you just tried to display them in a scene without trying to snapshot them.

Here is a png captured using the updated sample code from below:

[image: sample png]

*Graphs.java*

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class Graphs {

    private StackPane stackPane;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxisRight;
    private CategoryAxis xAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxisRightBlank;

    public Graphs() {
        stackPane = new StackPane();

        xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        ));

        yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 70, 10);
        yAxisRight = new NumberAxis(0, 14, 1);
        yAxisRightBlank = new NumberAxis(0, 15, 1);
        yAxisRightBlank.setSide(Side.RIGHT);

        xAxis.setLabel("Month");
        yAxis.setLabel("Level");
        yAxisRight.setLabel("Level (u)");
    }

    StackPane createGraphs() {
        BarChart<String, Number> barChart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        barChart.setLegendVisible(false);
        barChart.setAnimated(false);
        barChart.getXAxis().setVisible(true);

        barChart.getData().addAll(getAverageLoadPerFTE());

        LineChart<String, Number> lineChartEffective = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxisRight);
        lineChartEffective.setLegendVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.setAnimated(false);
        lineChartEffective.setCreateSymbols(true);
        lineChartEffective.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.getXAxis().setVisible(true);
        lineChartEffective.getYAxis().setVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.getYAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        lineChartEffective.getYAxis().setOpacity(0);

        lineChartEffective.getData().addAll(getEffectiveCustomerSupport());

        stackPane.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("overlay-chart.css").toExternalForm());
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(
                barChart,
                lineChartEffective
        );

        return stackPane;
    }

    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> getEffectiveCustomerSupport() {
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Jan", 2.9));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Feb", 2.7));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Mar", 3.3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Apr", 3.4));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("May", 3.3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Jun", 3.2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Jul", 3.3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Aug", 4));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Sep", 3.8));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Oct", 4.1));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Nov", 0));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Dec", 0));

        series.setName("Effective customer support");

        return series;
    }

    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> getAverageLoadPerFTE() {
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Jan", 58));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Feb", 54));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Mar", 47));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Apr", 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("May", 33));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Jun", 32));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Jul", 30));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Aug", 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Sep", 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Oct", 33));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Nov", 0));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Dec", 0));

        series.setName("Average load per FTE");

        return series;
    }
}
```

*GraphsApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class GraphsApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Graphs graphs = new Graphs();
        Pane graphPane = graphs.createGraphs();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(graphPane));
        stage.show();

        WritableImage snapshot = graphPane.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(),null);
        File graphFile = new File("chart.png");
        ImageIO.write(
                SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot,null),
                "png",
                graphFile
        );

        System.out.println("Wrote: " + graphFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*overlay-chart.css*

This file should end up in the same output directory for your build as the class files for the `Graphs` java class.

```
/** file: overlay-chart.css (place in same directory as LayeredXyChartsSample */
.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.default-color0.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: forestgreen;
}
```

Your code has lots of weird stuff involving a JavaFX `Task` and `Platform.runLater` calls.  For a task like this, none of those calls out to JavaFX concurrency constructs is needed or desirable, so I removed all of them.

Also, for future reference, when asked to provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please provide something which is both minimal (e.g. no FXML use if you don't need it to replicate the issue) and complete, so that somebody could just copy and paste it to run rather than having to spend time to make modifications, just to try to replicate the issue.

Note, with the updated code I provided, it can now draw and snapshot the stacked chart, however, I do not know if it is actually drawing the chart exactly as you wish it to be.  For example, the scale and range of x or y axis for each of the charts may not be as you wish relative to each other so the chart may or may not be plotted in a way which is "correct" for your combined data series.  If it is not correct, then you will need to address those issues separately.